List of Lecomte du Noüy Prize winners?
Is there a list of all Lecomte du Noüy Prize winners?
Pierre Lecomte du Noüy was a physicist and philosopher. Stanley L. Jaki, O.S.B. won the Lecomte du Noüy Prize for 1970, but I don't know who won it in other years. Is it similar to the Templeton Prize?

Scant information is available on recipients of this award.  A few I have found are Michael Polanyi in 1959 as reported in The Christian Scolar via jstor, Arthur Peacock in 1973  for Science and the Christian Experiment as reported on the John Templeton site, and Gautam Dasguptain 1980 for reasons unknown.  The award does not appear to be similar to the (secular) Templeton prize.

As it appears here (in French) the prize has been established by Vietnamese admirers of his "Téléfinalisme". René Barjavel was awarded the 1970 prize for his "La faim du tigre" (1966)

Antonio Colombo, webmaster of sljaki.com, wrote:

It is a sad story. The prize must have been awarded only once or twice (I have no other details). After receiving the prize (at Eccles's suggestion), Father Jaki somehow got involved with the related organization, but I think the widow De Nouy died almost immediately afterwards, and it was not followed up. There is a brief mention of it in A Mind's Matter, p. 112. I don't know what the prize really consisted of. […] In the curiosity department, Father Jaki for many years had two watches on his wrist (one on the right and one on the left). One of the two was De Nouy's, given to him by his widow. Something about the De Nouy affair can be guessed from Father Jaki's Publication List (at sljaki.com).

